# Javascript AJAX not getting executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The javascript is not executing the AJAX request, however the script is executed without AJAX. How can I execute scripts with AJAX which would be executed without ajax.

According to the following code I want the last line to be executed

Here I make an AJAX request to script ajax1.php

```
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
}
xmlhttp.open("GET", "ajax1.php?stateofmachine=xm234jqNewTemplateSelect" + "&q=" + str, true);
xmlhttp.send();
```

ajax1.php returns a table with class name as tree

```
echo "<table class=\"tree\">";
echo "<tr class=\"treegrid-1\">";
echo "<td>Root node</td>
echo  "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

ajax1.php also returns scripts

```
echo "<script src=
  \"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
  \"></script>";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=
  \"js/jquery.treegrid.min.js\"></script>";
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">$('.tree').treegrid();</script>";
```

Comment: Try with fetch api

Comment: has nothing to do with Ajax. The issue is innerHTML does not execute JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the responses. will think about the responses. can you quickly tell me if I can use anything instead of innerhtml.

Comment: Could you try to only return the last script of your AJAX, I thing you could incluide the scripts of jquery and treegrid in the "Master page" and just get the scripts like this: 
`<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>";<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.treegrid.min.js"></script>";<body>//your call here </body>`

Do you get an error? could you try with something more basic like an alert? Also use a funtion like document ready in your last script so it could be executed.

Comment: you are very correct in what you said. I have included the scripts in the master page and they did not work. you have indeed been very helpful. I will spend time analysing the various options you have listed. thanks for all the help.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197575/can-scripts-be-inserted-with-innerhtml

Comment: yeah thats a correct link. very helpful. i instantly understood one of the answers.So use this instead of script tags:

<img src="empty.gif" onload="alert('test');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" /> ... will try this and tell you the result.

Comment: on first trial <img src="empty.gif" onload="alert('test');this.parentNode.removeChild(this);" /> did not work from ajax. however i could be wrong. the if (document.readyState == "complete") executes scripts and i moved my script there. this worked for me.  thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> > added                 if (document.readyState == "complete") which executes the scripts..

```
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;

            if (document.readyState == "complete")
        {
            //document is ready.do your stuff here
        $('.tree').treegrid();
    }



        }
    };

    xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax1.php?stateofmachine=xm234jqNewTemplateSelect"+"&q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Comment: It would be nice if you explain what you did

Comment: the problem was the script returned from an ajax request was not getting executed.         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                if (document.readyState == "complete")
            {
                //document is ready.do your stuff here
            $('.tree').treegrid();
        }
i added if (document.readyState == "complete") and executed the script there.

Comment: You can edit your question by adding additional information and explanation. It would be much more elegant than comment ;)